# Tier Price not displaying Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm new to magento. I have one product having tier prices as follows:

```
a) 500 and above -> $46 
b) 1000 and above -> $43  
c) 1500 and above -> $39
```

And the Price(Actual) of product is $46. So on product detail page,  
It's not showing the first tier price (a). See below:

```
Buy 1000 for $43 each and save 7% 
Buy 2500 for $39 each and save 16%
```

Though the Actual price and minimum tier price are same, how can I display the minimum tier price in the above list. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your base product price is bigger then $46... If your base product price is lower then the tier price, the tier price wont show up.